# Отправка формы методом POST при полях input disabled="disabled"

Tags: javascript

Как отправить данные из формы методом POST, если некоторые поля input disabled="disabled"?
Это не позволяет отправить данные из формы. Есть ли способ или надо из делать abled и только после этого отправлять?

Answer (score 9):

```
<input name="input_name" type="text" value="input_value" readonly="" />
```

**`readonly=""`** вместо `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: Такой вариант не предусмотрен по некоторым причинам

Comment: может недопустим конктретно в вашем случае, а не - не предусмотрен?)

Comment: Просто даже интересно стало, какие могут быть на это причины? Ведь между disabled и readonly только в этом и разница, что readonly отправляется, а disabled нет.

Answer (score 1):

Тип поля *hidden* - использовать религия не позволяет?

Comment: Нет не позволяет. Конкретный вопрос можно или нет.

Comment: Бывает такое что при клике на такой input выпадает список сделаный уже ручками, кликая по элементу списка запись значения идет в этот инпут! Пользователя заполняющего определенную форму это веселит когда он видит что значение которое он выбрал отображается!

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, в вашем случае придется делать именно так, как вы и сказали: повесить на onsubmit функцию, разблокирующую все поля ввода (или лепящую с них input:hidden).

Answer (score -2):

Лично я вообще не пользуюсь сабмитом и соотвественно тега form избегаю, вместо этого присваиваю инпутам общий класс и отправлю их с помощью jquery.ajax(). ИМХО это намного удобнее.  Jquery отлично выберет все даже "отключенные" поля и отправит их куда вы укажете. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MqRNT/)

**UPD** Извиняюсь, допустил ошибку - сейчас все работает в примере.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: "?data="+$("input.submit").val()
});
```